# Access Oracle Http server(OHS) in a LAN

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, httpserver

I have configured OHS server infront of Weblogic to forward all request from OHS to WL server and it's working fine in local machine(where both WL and OHS are installed) and I could access the application deployed on WebLogic using OHS port.

```
 http://localhost:OHS_port/MyApp/,
 http://host_IP:OHS_port/MyApp/ and 
 http://127.0.0.1:OHS_port/MyApp/
```

all these url's working fine in the same machine where OHS and weblogic servers are deployed.

But when I try to access the same in LAN using OHS server port ,I am unable to access the application(http://host_IP:OHS_port/MyApp/), but same is accessible using weblogic port(http://host_IP:WL_port/MyApp/).

```
httpd.conf -

Listen 7777
ServerName 10.0.0.10:7777
(Rest of details in this files are default values)


mod_wl_ohs.conf -

<IfModule weblogic_module>
<Location /MyApp>
WLSRequest On
WebLogicHost 10.0.0.10
WeblogicPort 7001
</Location>
</IfModule>
```

Any idea why I am unable to access with OHS port? Is this something to do with firewall? If firewall issue, how I am able to access with weblogic port and not with OHS(I tried exchanging OHS and WL port and still the behavious is same(works with new weblogic port but not with OHS port)).

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some of the OHS config? What is the OHS listen address set to?

Comment: I have updated the config details which I modified. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your ServerName value should be the host name that you want OHS to respond on or the LAN IP address.

For instance, if the IP address of the machine is 10.1.1.10 and the hostname is myohs.mydomain.com, use the following:

ServerName myohs.mydomain.com

Also, be sure DNS is mapping myohs.mydomain.com to 10.1.1.10.

Comment: No, use the IP address of the server or even better use DNS and enter the DNS host for that value.

Comment: You could try using the machine name then for the ServerName value. Then access from outside this machine using http://machinename

Comment: That also I tried before and it didn't work. May be some issue with firewall? But I am confused how come I can access weblogic not OHS.

Comment: You don't need the port number in the ServerName value. What is the error when you try to access OHS directly?

Comment: Thank you for helping me on this, actually I tried with and without port as well and in both case it didn't work. I am not getting any error, just unable to access webpage error on the browser. I doubt it's not hitting OHS server itself. Even telnet with IP and port doesn't work and gives timeout.

Comment: Have you gotten just OHS working without WeLogic running at all? Maybe OHS isn't starting correctly if WebLogic is already bound on that port.

Comment: OHS is working fine on the host where it's deployed, I can access it's home page and even my application accessible on the same host. Problem is only if I try to access it from other machine in same network by using IP or host name. Now I moved OHS and WL setup to Linux machine and it's working perfectly fine with the same setup info. Thanks for the help.